# Object Detection using TFLearn or Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tflearn

I want to build a object detection model and cannot figure out whether to go for tensorflow object detection API or use TFLearn to build a model.Can someone tell me the pros and cons of both.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start with Tensorflow object detection Api, as you can quickly train your model from an existant raw model with ready config pipelines, you have many choices on your model architecture and backbone.
It is way easier and more sure, it is very popular and a huge community using it,
or you can use pytoch which i recommand, check https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. Object detection API is a standard builtin library you can quickly clone and use. It's good to learn it since it's popular across the industry because of the following reasons.

1. It's less error prone.
2. It saves your time
3. You can easily use tensorboard with it, to analyze the training stats.
4. It has inbuilt architectures like faster RCNN and SSD. You just have to understand using them. Understanding various hyperparameters in the config file and knowing to tune them is also a skill.

On the other hand if you want to make your own custom made models, you can go for learning tensorflow. Actually these both are not alternatives and should be learnt separately. In fact I would also suggest reading the research papers for the object detection algos available in the API.

Besides object detection tensorflow will also help you in long run, whether you are working on segmentation algos or autoencoders or anything else in DNNs.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API to do this very quickly for free/cheap.it is built on Resnet-20

https://rapidapi.com/mantis-object-detection-mantis-object-detection-default/api/mantis-object-detection/

Comment: @Yunnosch deleted the other two. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow has an object detection api that is capable of using tensorflow-2.0 and has GPU support. You can also play around with the configurations for model inference.

You can find it here: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
I'd also recommend trying out a few open source models like Faster-RCNN or Yolo models.

API: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/build-your-own-object-detection-model-using-tensorflow-api/

Yolo: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet